# test WCF server certificate on client side C#

Tags: c#, certificate, client-server

my client side UI has a window that runs some tests on the target server (ping , upload speed , download speed etc').
i want to add a test for the server certificate ( servers go through many installations , certificates are sometimes forgotten)

my code works just as i want it to. but i want to make sure i am not missing a better way to do it.

```
HttpWebRequest request = GetRequest(port,ipAddress);
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidationMethod;

try
{
   request.GetResponse();
   //if no exception is thrown then test passes
   return true;

}
//WebException  indicates a certifcate related issue
catch (System.Net.WebException e)
{
    return false
}
//general error handling
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

is there a better way to do this other then using exceptions as logic?

Comment: Certificates use different types of encryption like TLS/SSL which have different versions.  Some versions use 32 bit encryption and new versions use 64 bit encryption.  So to really test a certificate you have to check the settings in the certificate and write code to handle the different versions.  recently there were changes in Net library where people upgrade a project to newer versions of Net and the code stopped working because the default settings in Net changes.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: @jdweng  . the logic that validates the certificate is not in the scope of the problem. i have to assume that the ValidationMethod() is working as expected.

what i need to know if is what is the best way to detect it failed. now i'm catching a specific exception, i  would prefer not to do that.

Comment: I do not think the Net library has a validation method and you have to use the exception.